# Transform unicode \xe9 to é (python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, decode, encode, python-unicode

I'm trying to transform this unicode value:

> string_value = u'd\xe9cid\xe9'

to

> string_value = u'décidé'

I feel like I've tried everything:

```
decoded_str = string_value.decode('utf-8')
```

or

```
string_value = str(string_value)
decoded_str = string_value.encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
```

or

```
string_value = string_value.decode('latin-1')
```

for this one the result is:

> d\xc3\xa9cid\xc3\xa9

I have the same result if I do:

```
string_value = string_value.encode('utf-8')
```

I've read from:
[How do I convert 'blah \xe9 blah' to 'blah é blah'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27197507/how-do-i-convert-blah-xe9-blah-to-blah-%C3%A9-blah)

also from:
[Why does Python print unicode characters when the default encoding is ASCII?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596714/why-does-python-print-unicode-characters-when-the-default-encoding-is-ascii)

and:
[How do I convert a unicode to a string at the Python level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783079/how-do-i-convert-a-unicode-to-a-string-at-the-python-level)

EDIT:

My problem is I need to use the data, I mean if I have :

> string_value = u'mai 2017 \u2013 Aujourd\u2019hui'

which is :

> mai 2017 – Aujourd’hui

I want to do:

```
string_list = string_value.split('-')
```

But the result is:

```
[u'mai 2017 \u2013 Aujourd\u2019hui']
```

And I would:

```
['mai 2017', 'Aujourd’hui']
```

NEW EDIT:

I understand that I'm going to the wrong direction, thanks to your answer. 
\xe9 is the right representation of 'é' and it's not a problem.
My real issue is why does json.loads() transform 'mai 2017 – Aujourd’hui' to 'mai 2017 \u2013 Aujourd\u2019hui' ?

Comment: Why do you care how a string is represented in your source code? Does it not come out correctly when you `print` it?

Comment: string_value = string_value.encode('utf-8') is working for me in python2.7

Comment: `u'd\xe9cid\xe9'` already represents `u'décidé'`. You don't need to do anything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @usr2564301, the problem is I need to format the data. For exemple I've this unicode u'mai 2017 \u2013 Aujourd\u2019hui' that is 'mai 2017 – Aujourd’hui' and I want to split it at '-' and it's not working. I'm doing to edit my question with this exemple

Comment: `-` is simply not the same character as `–` (`\u2013`).

Comment: Don't edit your question in a way that invalidates all existing answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[splitting a string with a unicode delimiter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42323347/splitting-a-string-with-a-unicode-delimiter)

so...

```
print string_value.split(u"\u2013")
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you're asking: `\xe9` is a representation of the code point 233 (`e9` in hexadecimal), [which simply is the letter "é"](http://www.codetable.net/decimal/233):

```
>>> u'é' == u'\xe9'
True
```

Your confusion might stem from the fact that the `repr` of a Python string is (in Python 2) in ASCII, so non-ASCII characters are escaped. The Python console displays a value using `repr` if you do not `print` it explicitly:

```
>>> print(repr(u'é'))
u'\xe9'

>>> print(repr(u'\xe9'))
u'\xe9'
```

However, when you print the value, then it that conversion doesn't happen and everything works as expected:

```
>>> print(u'é')
é

>>> print(u'\xe9')
é
```

Also note that in Python 3, `repr` returns Unicode:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print(repr(u'\xe9'))
'é'
```

**Update after the question was edited:**

As pointed out in the comments, `\u2013` is not the same character as `-` (just as `a` and `b` are separate characters). So you'll need to split on `\u2013` instead of splitting on `-`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Florian for your answer, I've edited my question to explain better why is a problem for me

Comment: See my updates.

Comment: Ok thanks I understand perfectly now but there is a new question: why does json.loads() replace ' or - by \u ?

Comment: Please post additional questions as new posts if they are not closely related to the original question (which this one isn't).

Comment: @PAscalinox: indeed, why would it? Best guess is that it does *not* do so.